# Unable to use shared project in Xamarin app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to learn Xamarin, I have created a Xamarin project and a shared asset project. I have added that share asset project in my Xamarin project and also added its reference. But After adding this I am getting following compile error:

> /Users/pankajsachdeva/Projects/GreetingsSap/GreetingsSap/MyClass.cs(37,37):
>   Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ContentPage' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   (CS0246) (Hello)

Error Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Add the `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package to it

Comment: Hi Sushil, can you give me an example about where to add it? I have just got started with Xamarin.

Comment: Double-click on `From Packages`, search and add `Xamarin.Forms` and add a `using Xamarin.Forms` at the top of your code.

Comment: is this xamarin studio or visual studio? also have you worked on any .net frameworks before?

Comment: It is xamrin studio, No I have not worked on .net, although I have worked on iOS and Android

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You could use `Portable library` or `Xamarin.Forms Class Library` instead of `Shared Project Library` *(Shared Project Library is not able to add Reference)* and add `Xamarin.Forms` in the `Package` folder and add the header `using Xamarin.Forms` in your `MyClass.cs` file (as the screenshot above).